# mdadm/ext4 chunk size on raid 1

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, disk-space-utilization, ext4

Sorry for my noob question.

I have a raid 1 system on mdadm in Debian, with the resulting partition formatted as ext4. Looking at the resulting share in Windows, it reports:

Size: 618GB
Size on disk: 648GB

If I create an empty file, it reports 0 bytes for both. If I write a single character to the file it reports 'Size: 1 byte. Size on disk: 1MB'.

This is too large for the kind of files I'm storing. I thought the default allocation size on ext4 was 4kb? What have I done wrong / how can I fix this?

Comment: First, look at this data using the native system, not via a CIFS export. Also, can you provide the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md*` and `dumpe2fs /dev/md*`

Comment: Samba uses `allocation roundup size` for reporting the size to Windows clients. By default this setting is 1MiB and you could try to set this to `0 ` and check again. Restart Samba and reconnect your Windows client after you have made changes to `smb.conf`: